# Sketch the region defined by $Re z + Im z < 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to sketch the region given by $Re z + Im z < 1$, and I'm stuck.

For any complex number $z$, $Re z = x$ and $Im z = y$. Is this as simple as graphing the inequality $x + y < 1$, then? If not, then, how do I even begin to do this??

I'm having a lot of trouble graphing these regions/loci. Please help.

Comment: Draw the line $x+y=1.$ This line divides the plane in two semiplanes. Choose a point in each semiplane and guess which one you have to choose. Don't forget to delete the line because of $<.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is this as simple as graphing the inequality $x + y < 1$, then?"

Yes, that's exactly what it is.
That's what this problems asks you to do.